# C Array behaves different with different number of digits, why?

Tags: c, cs50

I have a code that gets a number from input and then puts it into array, and then prints said array. But there is very strange side-effect, when I enter 13 digit number, my last digit is wrong. If I enter 15 or 16 digit number everything is fine. I can't understand what's happening! Here is the code:
numberDigits is either 12, 14 or 15, based on the number of digits in number.

```
int myNumber[numberDigits];
    for (int i = 0; i <= numberDigits; i++)
    {
        myNumber[numberDigits - i] = number % 10;
        number = number / 10;         
    } 
    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i <= numberDigits; i++)

    {
        printf("%i",myNumber[i]);
    }
```

EDIT:
My number is initialized as long long int. Here is a check to verify number of digits:

```
    if (number / 1000000000000 >= 1 && number / 1000000000000 < 10)
    {
        numberDigits = 12;
    } 
if (number / 100000000000000 >= 1 && number / 100000000000000 < 10)
    {
        numberDigits = 14;
    }
if (number / 1000000000000000 >= 1 && number / 1000000000000000 < 10)
    {
        numberDigits = 15;
    }
```

EDIT: Last update, Yes, I have updated my code and it works as expected with your suggestions, but I need to understand why my code doesn't work. I think that maybe array[12] actually holds 12 elements and not 13, and when I access element array[12] with it, I get some random value from memory, but why this doesn't happen with array[14] or array[15] with 15 and 16 digit numbers respectively. And why program does not crash as it should when you access array at wrong position. Original question below with old code that doesn't work.

EDIT: Here is whole listing for those interested.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int verify (long long int number);

int main(void)

{
    printf("Please enter card number: \n");
    long long int number = GetLongLong();
    // AMEX uses 15 digits
    if (number > 100000000000000 && ((number / 10000000000000 == 34) || (number / 10000000000000 == 37)))
    {        

        printf("AMEX");

    }

    if (number > 1000000000000 && number < 10000000000000 && (number / 1000000000000 == 4))
    {
        printf("VISA");
    }

    if (number > 1000000000000000 && number < 9999999999999999 && (number / 1000000000000000 == 4))
    {
        printf("VISA");
    }

        if (number > 1000000000000000 && number < 9999999999999999 && (number / 100000000000000 == 51 || number / 100000000000000 == 52 || number / 100000000000000 == 53 || number / 100000000000000 == 54 || number / 100000000000000 == 55))
    {
        printf("MASTERCARD");
    }

    return verify(number); 
}



int verify (long long int number)
{
    int numberDigits;
    if (number / 1000000000000 >= 1 && number / 1000000000000 < 10)
        {
            numberDigits = 12;
        } 
    if (number / 100000000000000 >= 1 && number / 100000000000000 < 10)
        {
            numberDigits = 14;
        }
    if (number / 1000000000000000 >= 1 && number / 1000000000000000 < 10)
        {
            numberDigits = 15;
        }       

    int myNumber[numberDigits];
    for (int i = 0; i <= numberDigits; i++)
    {
        myNumber[numberDigits - i] = number % 10;
        number = number / 10;         
    } 
    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i <= numberDigits; i++)

    {
        printf("%i",myNumber[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberDigits; ++i) printf("%d",myNumber[i]);
```

instead of:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= numberDigits; ++i) printf("%i",myNumber[i]);
```

And in the first loop:

```
myNumber[numberDigits - (i + 1)] = number % 10;
```

Also, you could use something like this to know the number of digits:

```
int digits(long long num) {
  if(!num) return 1;
  return log10(num) + 1;
}
```

Comment: This works, but what is wrong with my code? It is basically the same on all levels. Why the trailing number changes, if for example I input 9837367482735 it give me 9837367482731, but if I input 15 or 16 digit number it is all correct.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, but maybe you're doing something else. Put the entire code to see what could be wrong.

Comment: You should try and put what I first suggested:

    ``myNumber[numberDigits - (i + 1)] = number % 10;``

Comment: Yes, I have updated my code and it works as expected with your suggestions, but I need to understand why my code doesn't work. I think that maybe array[12] actually holds 12 elements and not 13, and when I access array[12] with it, I get some random value from memory, but why this doesn't happen with array[14] or array[15] with 15 and 16 digit numbers respectively. And why program does not crash as it should when you access array at wrong position.

Comment: If you declare an array like this: ``int arr[20]`` you cannot access the index 20, just from 0 to 19, that's why in the loop you would be also counting the length of the array, which in this case is 20, and it may cause some errors, and at the same time, when you do something like ``arr[arr.size - i]`` eventually you're going to access ``arr[20]`` (when i = 0) and then again, you can't do that.

Comment: Yes, ``int array[12]`` only contains 12 elements. And it won't always crash, just overwrite the value of the direction assigned to what would be ``array[12]``

Answer (score 3):

Your `for` loop should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberDigits; i++)
```

Since indexes are zero-based, the last one will be `numberDigits - 1`. And so `<=` would go past the end.

Comment: If I do it like this, my first number is zero and is wrong. Since for 13 digit number i use array[12], my last digit is still 0.

Comment: I see. Yes, a bit more work is needed. But I'm having trouble with your code. Where does `number` get initialized first time through?

Comment: did, I get 0xxxxxxxxxxx insted of correct number, and missing last digit. As I said, it works like this, first is zero, etc, ends when numberDigits is 12 and 12 is last in array too, so <= works just fine and problem is not in it.